# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type '<anonymous type:?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Call_Info_extra](
    [Call_Info_extra_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nurse_account_login_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [rescuer_info] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [amb_plates_1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [amb_plates_2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Call_Info_extra_constr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Call_Info_extra_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'm trying to retrieve data from this table and add them to dictionary.

```
var call_info_extra = entities.Call_Info_extra.Where(c => c.nurse_account_login_id == query[0].nurse_account_login_id).Select(c => new { c.rescuer_info, c.amb_plates_1, c.amb_plates_2 }).FirstOrDefault(); ;
IDictionary<string, string> myNurseAccount = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myNurseAccount.Add("rescuer_info", call_info_extra[0].rescuer_info);
```

In the last code line I get the following error:

> Error CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type '<anonymous type: ? rescuer_info, ? amb_plates_1, ? amb_plates_2>'

Comment: You asked for the _**First**_ or default record. There's no array or collection, there is no `[0]` item. I's just  `call_info_extra.rescuer_info` (assuming you have a result at all)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you! That's it. Add it as an answer to accept it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn In case I don't have a result, this will be `Null` value, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for the ***First*** or default record. There's no array or collection, there is no `[0]` item. It's just  `call_info_extra.rescuer_info` (assuming you have a result at all). If there's no record, the `OrDefault` part of the name means you get the default `null` value for a reference type, and then the expression will produce a `NullReferenceException` trying to lookup the `rescuer_info` property from that `null` reference.